# routing index.php with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am running wamp on win7 just in case. I am trying to route all requests through a `route.php` to get clean URLs. Below is my htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(auth|folder2) [NC]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*) ./route.php?path=$1 [L]
```

As you can see the rule should apply to all files, and it  did when I ran it on my old wamp installation. Now after copying the files to a new system, for some reason, the rule seems to work for all links **except** `index.php`. So if I try `http://localhost/proj`, I get no routing in the new system. Any ideas?

And before anyone asks, yes `rewrite_module` is on, and the `htaccess` is being read and executed cause it works for all other links like `http://localhost/proj/users` and also because if I try putting garbage values in the htaccess it throws a nice 'internal server error'.

Comment: is it because you're directing to _route.php_ rather than _index.php_ ?

Comment: @Loopo I am not sure what you mean but what I am trying to do is internally load `index.php` via `route.php`, so `localhost/proj` should be seen internally as something like `localhost/proj/route.php?index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you have an index.php in that folder, and this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
```

...tells apache to perform the rewrite only if the file does not exist.

I would suggest or renaming the file, as you'll need that condition to route static assets like images, scripts, etc.

If there is no index.php (or index.htm[l]) in that folder, just define route.php as the default file in that directory. In your .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex route.php index.php index.html index.htm
```

(Be aware that this will also apply to any sub-directories as well)